# programmatically detect SIM change in android

Tags: java, android

Is there any way that I can do the following things programmatically in Android ?

- know the SIM or the IMSI exists in the phone after knowing it, if
- any change happen to it i can detect it and know the new SIM or IMSI
  entered.

**to get back with a new IMSI if changed or message telling that no sim change or IMSI change**

help me please with simple code cause I'm new to development  :( 
i tried following the examples but couldn't understand for its complexity

Comment: So you had examples but couldn't follow them-  how do you expect us to help?  People don't write examples with the point of overcomplicating them, odds are those were the easiest way to do it.

Comment: 1- identify your problem to be able to solve it. 2- understand your problem.

Comment: Can you post what did you try and what didn't work? No one is going to write you code here until you try and get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code to get the SIM card ID

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     
 String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Store the data in SharedPreferences and again use the above code to get the SIM card ID every time you open the app and check the new SIM card ID with that ID which is stored in the SharedPreferences. If the data is different, that means the SIM card is changed and you can process further according to your requirement.

Comment: This will not be working in android Q and above.